# Primitive keywords for R

Tags: python, r, keyword

What are the primitive keywords in R? For example, in Python `del`, `assert`, `if`, `else` and so on are all keywords. In R it seems only some of these are keywords, but some are rather functions from some (unknown) library, or some weird "syntax hacks", such as using `df[-c(1),]` to delete the first row of observations*. [Here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Vocabulary.html) I found some of list, but I'm not sure if those aren't just basic functions, instead of primitive keywords.
Unfortunately the documentation of R is overwhelming and after spending some time with it, I was able to find such a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be seen by "typing `help(reserved)` or `?reserved` at the R command prompt"([source](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/reserved-words)).

The full list, according to the above site as of posting, is:

> if, else, repeat, while, function, for, in, next, break, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, Inf, NaN, NA, NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_complex_, NA_character_